# Can't get static function to work php

Tags: php

So I wan't to create this function:

```
public static function formclean($string) {
    htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($string)));
    return $string;
}
```

Where the string gets prepared for MySQL database entry. However, when I call my function I:

```
$class->string = Class::formclean($_POST['string']);
```

It doesn't return the prepared string. When I write the next bit of code it does work.

```
$class->string = htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST['string'])));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are making manipulations inside this function, but are returning the unmanipulated version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to capture the return value of `htmlentities()` into a variable:

```
public static function formclean($string) {
    $string = htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($string)));
    return $string;
}
```

Or, for short, just return that output directly:

```
public static function formclean($string) {
    return htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($string)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your issue has nothing to do with the `static` keyword.
2. You assume that `$string` gets modified by [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) but such function doesn't receive parameters by reference: there's no way it can modify the original value.

   > s`tring htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = 'UTF-8' [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )`

   A function that receives args by refrence would feature a **&** symbol, e.g. [sort()](http://php.net/sort):

   > `bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )`
3. `strip_tags()` has nothing to do with databases or validation. It's just a way to corrupt user data. The [proper way to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) is to use your database library features to inject parameters (namely prepared statements).

Comment: I see. I will take your advice. Thanks for replying!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm fed up of posting comments to programming sites just to find out my code is gone after the first `<` symbol ;-)